# Nifi:How to remove xml tag from xml response data?

Tags: xml, apache-nifi

I want to replace `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`  tag by `<DailyData></DailyDate>`

I  used to replace text nifi  processor  with this search  value:`^<[^>]+>(.*)<\/\w+>$` and I put replace  value  like this in replace 
 value `<DailyData>$1</DailyData>` but I  got error  like  this inside xml  file:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 4081: XML declaration allowed only at the
>   start of the document Below is a rendering of the page up to the first
>   error.

what should I  change?

Comment: It seems like the header is included twice. Have you reviewed your XML after remove the header tag?

Comment: Yes it doesn't have this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: but i can't add  this tag  <DailyData></DailyDate>

Answer (score 1):

If your XML document has something like the following line at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Then your ReplaceText is wrapping that in the  tags. If you know what that header line is supposed to look like, you can match it exactly (or otherwise grab just the first line), then use that group in the replace value, something like `$1<DailyData>$2</DailyData>`.

Comment: I have added  $1  in searchvalue and  this expression in replace text $1<DailyData>$2</DailyData> but it haven't added  <DailyDate><.DailyData< tage

Comment: You have to add a group to the regex to capture the first line, then the first group will be the header line and the second group will be everything else